# A problem of energy conservation in GR

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, energy-conservation, vector-fields

The following discussion with the Minkowskian space-time.
It is known that the conservation is described by $P_{\xi}=\int_{\Sigma} T_{a b} n^{a} \xi^{b}$, where $\Sigma$ is a Cauchy surface and $n^a$ is the normal vector of $\Sigma$. $\xi^{b}$ is killing vector. now we choose a reference{t,xi} let $n^{a}=(\partial / \partial t)^{a}$, $ \xi^{b}=(\partial / \partial t)^{b}$ and $P$ represents the energy conservation.

However, if there is another Cauchy surface $\Sigma'$,$n'^{a}$ is perpendicular to $\Sigma'$. here, we still choose killing vector  $ \xi^{b}=(\partial / \partial t)^{b}$. It is easy to show that $P=P'$,  people say this means energy conservation. but i believe it is wrong!!!  Firstly, you should give a certain reference when it comes to energy, in this case the reference is {t,xi} of course. Secondly, energy conservation means it does not change at each moment and each moment will define a unique simultaneous surface that is parallel to xi($\Sigma$) as showed in red parallel arrow in figure. however, $\Sigma'$ is not a simultaneous surface in the case, so we can not say $\Sigma'$ is at which moment, maybe one can choose a new reference where $\Sigma'$is one of simultaneous surface but not in{t,xi}reference!!! and P' can not represent the whole space at a certain moment so $P=P'$ does not represent the energy conservation.
 can anyone give me some suggestion?
[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. Show that $P=P{'}$. And you need to define what you mean by Minkowskian space. Is it a compact manifold with closed time curves?

Comment: just  Minkowskian space-time ,the flat space-time

Comment: Unless you make topological change to Minkowski space, then your statement is false. And drawing a picture isn't a proof.

Comment: @Liwei_Wang: actually, you should ask the OP this question since it's OP argument that $R(1,3)$ where EM lives is broken. My argument is that it's the breaking up of $R(1,3)$ into $R\times S^3$ that is broken and that $R(1,3)$ is the gold standard of causality.

Comment: you mean Minkowski space?, Minkowski space is RxR^3. and there is no closed time curve. by the way, my question is in Minkowski space.

Comment: @Liwei_Wang:No, Minkowski spacetime is $R(1,3)$, Minkowski time and COMPACT space is $R\times S3$, and $R$ time and $R^{3}$ space is where you live. The 3 spaces are different. – Cinaed Simson 5 mins

Comment: it has nothing to do with my question. we just assume the general  Minkowski spacetime@CinaedSimson

Comment: @Liwei_Wang: okay, assuming you're read and understood the OP's post - which is questionable since you claim there's no problem with EM but the OP claims there is. In any case, the burden of proof is on the OP.